# Python - Beautiful Soup to grab emails from website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to figure out a simple way to run through a set of URLs that lead to pages that all have the same layout. We figured out that one issue is that in the original list the URLs are http but then they redirect to https. I am not sure if that then causes a problem in trying to pull the information from the page. I can see the structure of the page when I use Inspector in Chrome, but when I try to set up the code to grab relevant links I come up empty (literally). The most general code I have been using is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://ngcproject.org/program/algirls').read())
links = SoupStrainer('a')
print links
```

which yields:

```
a|{}
```

Given that I'm new to this I've been trying to work with anything that I think might work. I also tried:

```
mail = soup.find(attrs={'class':'tc-connect-details_send-email'}).a['href']
```

and

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'tc-connect-details_send-email'})
lines = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
print lines
```

but these don't yield anything either.

I am assuming that it's an issue with my code and not one that the data are hidden from being scraped. Ideally I want to have the data passed to a CSV file for each URL I scrape but right now I need to be able to confirm that the code is actually grabbing the right information. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: The reason this does not work is because the content is filled it at render time by angular.

Comment: Which means that you should use dynamic crawling tools, like *e.g.* selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If you press CTRL+U on Google Chrome or Right click > view source.
You'll see that the page is rendered by using javascript or other.
urllib is not going to be able to display/download what you're looking for.
You'll have to use automated browser (Selenium - most popular) and you can use it with Google Chrome / Firefox or a headless browser (PhantomJS).

You can then get the information from Selenium and store it then manipulate it in anyway you see fit.